# How to code in Xcode/Swift 'post' API to post votes to Drupal7 Fivestar module field with Voting API Services

Tags: swift, post, drupal-7

I am a beginner. How do I code a 'Post' request to submit a vote to the Drupal 7 Fivestar module field ("field_fivestar_rating') of my content nodes? From my research, it seems to me the Fivestar accesses the Voting API. I've set up the Drupal Voting API services

This page https://www.drupal.org/node/2145873 suggests that to set votes I need to do a POST to rest/votingapi/set_votes.json with this json:

```
{
  "votes": [
    {
      entity_id: 2,
      value_type: "points",
      tag: "vote",
      value: 11
    }
]
}
```

How do I add these parameters or adapt my below code to send eg vote 10 to node 1234 (Nid 1234) to post to the field 'field_fivestar_rating'. Thank you for any help/tips you could kindly give? Here is the code I'm trying:

```
// Define server side script URL
let ratingscriptUrl = "https://example.com/rest/votingapi/set_votes.json"

// Create NSURL Ibject
let myUrl = NSURL(string: ratingscriptUrl)

// Create URL Request
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);

// Set POST request
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// Add parameters for voting API 'ratings' field of node
let result: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["entity_id": 2, "value_type" : "points", "tag": "vote", "value": 11]
let json = JSON(result).rawString()
request.HTTPBody = json!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

// Execute HTTP Request
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
 data, response, error in

// Check for error
     if error != nil
  {
     print("error=\(error)")
     return
  }
```

Xcode brings up error message "use of unresolved identifier JSON" on this line:
     let json = JSON(result).rawString()

Comment: `unresolved identifier JSON` There's no `JSON` type in Swift. There is one in the third-party library named SwiftyJSON. Maybe, without realizing it, you're using code that needs this lib?

Comment: you are correct. That removed the unresolved identifier, thank you. I will check the code.

Comment: With firefox poster I have successfully put a 'post request' to the server with these parameters (and example values): {"votes":[{"entity_id": 16610, "uid":"3", "value_type":"percent", "tag":"vote", "value":"80"}]}

Comment: There's probably what you need among these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswift%5d%20post%20json%20parameters